# calling multiple action from an effect

Tags: ngrx

**please watch the edit**

I have an effect that will retrieve from http a list of object.

When retrieved, I want that same effect to dispatch for each object an action that will open a channel in order to get live update of those object

```
  @Effect()
  getUsedDrones$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<featureActions.GetUsedDronesRequest>(featureActions.ActionTypes.GetUsedDronesRequest),
    switchMap((action) =>
      this.droneDataService.getUsedDrones(action.payload).pipe(
        map(drones => {
          drones.forEach((drone) => new featureActions.OpenUsedDroneUpdateChannelRequest({ droneId: drone.id, projectId : environment.projectId }));
          new featureActions.GetUsedDronesSuccess({drones});
        }),
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          this.snackBar.open(this.translate.instant('ERRORS.HTTP.GENERIC'), this.translate.instant('BUTTONS.OK'), {duration: 2500});
          return of(new featureActions.GetUsedDronesFailed({error}));
        }),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

basically, after calling my api and retrieving the drones, I need to call this for each drone

```
    map(drones => {
      drones.forEach((drone) => new featureActions.OpenUsedDroneUpdateChannelRequest({ droneId: drone.id, projectId : environment.projectId }));
      new featureActions.GetUsedDronesSuccess({drones});
    }),
```

and then trigger the success of the retrieval.

the other action will basically call this

```
  startUpdate$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<featureActions.OpenUsedDroneUpdateChannelRequest>(featureActions.ActionTypes.OpenUsedDroneUpdateChannelRequest),
    switchMap((action) =>
      this.droneDataService.openUsedDroneUpdateChannel(action.payload).pipe(
        map(result => {
          if (this.currentUpdateEventList.has(action.payload.droneId)) { return; }
          new featureActions.OpenUsedDroneUpdateChannelSuccess(result);
          this.currentUpdateEventList.set(action.payload.droneId, [
            `get_position_drone${action.payload.droneId}`,
            `get_status_drone${action.payload.droneId}`
          ])
          this.sseService.subscribe(`get_position_drone${action.payload.droneId}`, (position: Cartesian3) => {
            new featureActions.SetUsedDronePosition({droneId : action.payload.droneId, position});
          });
          this.sseService.subscribe(`get_status_drone${action.payload.droneId}`, (status: IDroneStatus) => {
            new featureActions.SetUsedDroneStatus({droneId : action.payload.droneId, status});
          });
        }),
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          this.snackBar.open(this.translate.instant('ERRORS.HTTP.DRONE.NOT_UPDATABLE', {droneId: action.payload.droneId}), this.translate.instant('BUTTONS.OK'), {duration: 2500});
          return of(new featureActions.OpenUsedDroneUpdateChannelFailed({error}));
        }),
      )
    )
  );
```

Now, the problem I have is the following, My first foreach return this error

> core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Effect "UsedDronesEffect.getUsedDrones$"
>   dispatched an invalid action: undefined
>
> core.js:15724 ERROR TypeError: Actions must be objects
>       at ActionsSubject.push../node_modules/@ngrx/store/fesm5/store.js.ActionsSubject.next

**EDIT :** I Fixed the error but, now my forEach action are not dispatched

```
    map(drones => {

      drones.forEach((drone) => new featureActions.OpenUsedDroneUpdateChannelRequest({ droneId: drone.id, projectId : environment.projectId }));
      return new featureActions.GetUsedDronesSuccess({drones});
    }),
```

How can I return a list of action based on the amount of drone I have, and end up with success ?

**EDIT 2 :**

shouldn't this work ?

```
map(drones => {
  const actions = [];
  drones.forEach((drone) => actions.push(new featureActions.OpenUsedDroneUpdateChannelRequest({ droneId: drone.id, projectId : environment.projectId })));
  actions.push(new featureActions.GetUsedDronesSuccess({drones}));
  return merge(actions);
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out. I hope this will resolve your issue.

[dispatching multiple actions from single Effect @ngrx](https://medium.com/@amcdnl/dispatching-multiple-actions-from-ngrx-effects-c1447ceb6b22)

Comment: I checked this, but here the action are "static", mine depends on the amount so I need a way to dispatch an array of Action with different params

Comment: You can queue them up in a single array and dispatch at once before you return from the function. You can flatten them up before emit from the Observable.